# How can we know ID of the document on client side

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb

I have recently learned tutorial about restful APIs.In that, my instructor suggested me that if we want to delete any document we should pass id in the parameter of the request. But now I am confused How do we handle this implementation on the client side.I mean how can even the programmer on the front side could be aware of that particular document ID. Does he need to go to the database each time?

Answer (score 1):

Common practice for accessing a record in db is to use its unique identifier, to get or update or delete the record.
On the client side (if you mean user interface) when user wants to delete a document, he/she must see the document somewhere in the interface. Suppose a page with a table containing a list of all (for instance) books in the db. On each row, you have book title and author's name and the `id` of the book document in the db.
So you can use that `id` to call the delete rest API.
In a nutshell, when you want to delete something you must have got it from db to simply see it, so the `id` is at your hand.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to delete a  some doc from the database you need to get all documents to the front end to see what do we need to do to this data right ?

Imagine any database GUI that u have worked with.. 
let's say phpmyadmin when using mysqli
in that case you have php mydamin's GUI so that u can clearly see what are the tables and how things persist in the database. you need to see that in order for you to make decision 
. Like that you will need to bring at least a portion of that data to the front end for user to see it and choose what portion of data the user want's to make changes or delete.

so when we have a set of data in the front end like a list, if a user select one item from that list the id or the name of that item can be send to the server side and make the task if the user wishes to do 
that's why you need an Id or a identification field of that particular data..